# Switch crashes when clicked on Android 5.0

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-switch

When clicking on a switch in my app in Android 5.0 the app crashes with the logcat shown below. The logcat doesn't reference my code anywhere in it, and this switch has worked fine on all previous versions. The switch appears invisible except for the background color and only crashes once clicked on.

After testing, the same thing happens whether I define a setOnCheckedChangeListener function or not. Even if the switch is in the layout but never in the code it will still crash when clicked on.

One of the switches in question:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Airborn"
    android:textOn="Direct Contact"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/switchWind"/>
```

And here's how I reference it.

```
// Doesn't actually matter since same thing happens without this
Switch sWind = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchWind);
sWind.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
        // Won't reach here
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
11-17 22:09:18.722  30190-30190/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
11-17 22:09:18.722  30190-30190/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-17 22:09:18.735  30190-30190/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Switch.hitThumb(Switch.java:694)
        at android.widget.Switch.onTouchEvent(Switch.java:711)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-17 22:09:18.735  30190-30190/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-17 22:09:18.736  30190-30190/com.egondev.android.patientzerotest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.egondev.android.patientzerotest, PID: 30190
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Switch.hitThumb(Switch.java:694)
        at android.widget.Switch.onTouchEvent(Switch.java:711)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: If you only define Switch view in xml and not doing any code related switch in activity then same error came ?

Comment: take a look, its bug with Android 5.0
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like a known issue in Android 5.

Please refer the following link :

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704

Comment: Crazy that made it past QA. Apparently the switch is not a widely used feature.

Comment: Then how to resolve this issue. Is this issue fixed? Please canbody tell me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just change thumb and track images for the switch.

Comment: What do we change it to?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the theme in manifest file worked for me.
i had android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

and changed it into
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"

Comment: Same issue with 5.0.2. With NoTitleBar theme switcher is broken =(

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue at Sony tablet with Android 5.0.2 - Switch crash my app when activity style is NoTitleBar / FullScreen.

What worked well for me, is to set FullScreen mode in code and not inside manifest.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

If I don't mess something up, the results is the same as usuall, but without crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing:

```
android:thumb="@null"
```

to:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/transparent_thumb"
android:track="@drawable/transparent_track"
```

transparent_thumb & transparent_track are two png files which are transparent. They have matched size to your customized Switch.