# Switch control is not working on Dialog in Android version 5.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-switch

I have used below `switch` in my application.

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=""
        android:thumb="@drawable/toggle_button_color"
        android:textOff="@string/text_estimate"
        android:textOn="@string/text_accurate" 
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

In above `switch` I am using `toggle_button_color.xml` to change the thumb color to green and red when `switch` is on and off respectively.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />   
</selector>
```

If I add this `switch` to an activity layout and then its wokring perfectly as below image.
[image]  [image]

But if I add this `switch` on `Dialog` using `m_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);` then switch looks like below.
Note that here `mylayout.xml` is a `layout` file in which I have added `switch`.

[image]

For android version below 5.0 lollipop `switch` is working fine as I want. Note that for some reasons I am using `Theme.Holo.Light` in my application so I can't use `SwitchCompat`.

I know that a similar question has been asked here [Switch crashes when clicked on Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987994/switch-crashes-when-clicked-on-android-5-0).

And also it is reported here https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704.
I have also tried the work around which is mentioned in above link to add drawable image for thumb and track, but I don't understand why same switch is working on `activity layout` but not on `Dialog`.

Can anybody please help me out with this?

Comment: I've followed your setup with the available info (i.e. I don't know how you've set up your Dialog), but I cannot recreate the same result - the switch works on Nexus 7 2013 with Android 5.1 and on Android 5.0 emulator. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your response, but I solved it by my own. Earlier I was implementing the dialog using the `Dialog` class, which was causing the problems.

```
Dialog mDialog= new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

I have even tried changing the `themes` but it didn't help.

Then I tried using `DialogFragment`, which solved the issue.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
    return v;
    }
}
```

And from my `Activity` class I invoke this `Dialog` as below.

```
MyDialog mDialog = new MyDialog();
mDialog .show(getFragmentManager(), "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without seeing your `Dialog` instantiation code (please add that if you can), but it sounds like there's a discrepancy between the `Theme` being used for your `Activity` and the theme being used for your `Dialog`.  You may want to experiment with explicitly specifying the `Dialog`'s `Theme` using the `public Dialog (Context context, int theme)` [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog(android.content.Context,%20int)).